# When can we exercice an option?

Tags: options, call-options, option-exercise

Can we only exercice an option when it expire ?

For exemple I have an Adobe option with a strike price of 87.50$ and expiring on 2016-01-15. Adobe stock have already raised above my strike price. Could I exercice my option right away ?

Comment: If you are trading options then you should know the answer to this question. Most brokers would not let you have an option account unless you can demonstrate some knowledge about options. Why are you trading something you know very little about?

Comment: @GeorgeRenous This is a question and answer site. He asked a perfectly reasonable question. I don't think it's appropriate to chastise him for it. (And since he has a long position, his loss is limited.)

Comment: @TainToTain - George is correct. That is why people lose money when investing. They see or hear others doing it so say I can do it too. They get involved in things they don't understand and then whinge when they lose money. If the OP was asking the question because he/she was learning about options before trading them, then that would be different, but considering the OP already is trading options then he/she should already know the answer to this basic question.

Comment: @TainToTain - so often we get a question after the fact. "Mom died and the bank handed me $1M cash from her IRA 90 days ago. Will I owe any tax?" Our inclination is to respond that OP should ask first, before any transaction. In this case, the only mistake made was that OP bought something he clearly didn't understand. George's comment was blunt, but not inappropriate.

Comment: When ITM, Close or Adjust your Option position, to lock in profit.

Comment: @George Renous: Yay, judgemental assumptions... I don't trade options, I'm practicing on a simulator (on investopedia), but thanks remaining constructive in your answer and being so willing to share your great knowledge so other can learn from your immense expertise.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer: I didn't buy anything, I'm learning and practicing on a trading simulator...?

Comment: Well, that's exactly what we'd recommend. Practice on paper, learn first. Options are a niche, but a few members here are knowledgable and happy to help.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Well when I read a comment like this, "happy to help" is not exactly the feeling it gives me.

Might be new on the money stack, but been active on other stack sites and if you start going off-topic talking about yourself, you get that edited away to keep the question to the point for others who will find it down the road. I almost got shot down for following that rule.

George Renous could have crafted an answer with a tactful warning in it, but choose instead not to share his knowledge and shut me down. Not cool.

Comment: @FMaz008, well maybe you should have included that you were practicing on a simulator in your question, because your question as it stands gives the impression that you are actually trading them; "For example I have an Adobe option...". If you are not clear in your questions you get people giving you a whole lot of wrong answers because they don't have the whole picture.

Comment: In fact when I made my comment you could have easily mentioned that you were just using a simulator and edited your question as such, but instead you have left your question as is, still leaving confusion unless someone reads your comments way below the actual question.

Comment: Stack questions are to be as concise as possible. The detail on wether I use a simulator or not has no influence on the answer to the question, which is already very clear for any future readers. Please read stack guidelines.

Comment: @FMaz008, adding that you are using a simulator would not make it less concise, it would add about 4 words. If you didn't want to add that then you should had left out that "...I have an Adobe option..." To make it more concise and not mislead anyone. If you want a better answer and less criticism then include any relavent and specific information in your question. And like I said from the start if someone was trading in real life (as your question suggests) and doesn't know the answer to your question, then they are plain stupid and looking to lose money.

Comment: On other stacks, I got edited for saying "Hello" and/or "Thank you".

Comment: @FMaz008 - I don't think being more specific and having all relevant information about your situation is the same as writing "Hello" or "Thank you" I think you are totally missing the point, how does saying "Hello" or "Thank you" help someone answering your question? Being specific and having all relevant information, however, would help someone answer your question and help them avoid making wrong assumptions about you or your question.

Comment: @victor how would any of thoses anwsers would have been any different? The guy didn't even bother posting one...

Comment: @FMaz008 - the answer you chose as the best was basically copied and pasted from Investopedia, something you could have easily checked yourself. And really any book or text on the subject of Options would have this information in it. If you had opened up a simulator the broker or other provider you used should have educational material covering this information. And if you had been really trading, as your question suggests, then well that has already been talked about. But just because 3 answers didn't pick up on this does not mean that your question could not have been improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

American options (like those on ADBE) can be exercised by the holder anytime before expiration. They will be exercised automatically at expiration if they are in the money. However, if there is still time before expiration (as in this case), and they are not extremely in the money, there is probably extrinsic value to the option, and you should sell it, not exercise it.

European options are only automatically exercised at expiration, and only if they are in the money. These are usually cash settled on products like SPX or VIX. They can not be exercised before expiration, but can be sold anytime.

Answer (score 5):

> Owners of American-style options may exercise at any time before the
>   option expires, while owners of European-style options may exercise
>   only at expiration.

[Read more: American Vs. European Options](http://www.investopedia.com/articles/optioninvestor/08/american-european-options.asp#ixzz3tByu0m8D)

Comment: This is the right answer, but you generally never want exercise prior to expiration. The option still has time value (extrinsic value). When you sell, all you get is intrinsic value. You're giving away a lot of value by prematurely exercising. When you factor in broker costs, it's generally even cheaper to just sell the option just before expiration. Honestly, most derivatives are only traded (and subsequently closed) and not exercised, even if they're used for hedging, not speculation (think about a manager rolling over a hedge).

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about ADBE options, that is an American style option, which can be exercised at any time before expiration. You can exercise your options by calling your broker and instructing them to exercise. Your broker will charge you a nominal fee to do so.

As an aside, you probably don't want to exercise the option right now. It still has a lot of time value left, which you'll lose if you exercise. Just sell the option if you don't think ADBE will keep going up.

Comment: +1 from me, welcome to money.se, nice answer. Time value makes this more than a yes/no question.